# Traverse Through XML

Tags: xml, go

I have an XML string

```
str := "<data><node><value>Foo</value></node></data>"
```

I need to replace value with another value (`Bar`). Given a path

```
"data.node.value"
```

Is there a way in Go to find and replace that value? So calling `Replace(str, "data.node.value","Bar")`

```
<data><node><value>Bar</value></node></data>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible, since you just have a string.
You need to

1. Unmarshal the XML into a struct,
2. then manipulate the struct
3. then marshal it back into a string.

Something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Data struct {
    Node Node `xml:"node"`
}

type Node struct {
    Value string `xml:"value"`
}

func main() {
    str := "<data><node><value>Foo</value></node></data>"

    var d Data
    xml.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &d)  // unmarshal it

    d.Node.Value = "Bar" // manipulate the struct

    xmlout, _ := xml.Marshal(d) // re-marshal it

    fmt.Println("result: ", string(xmlout))
}
```

Comment: So how can I traverse thru a struct given a string?

Comment: You need to unmarshal it if you want to traverse or manipulate the dom.
I'm 99% sure that its not possible to traverse a string. A string has no concept of the xml structure, it is just a slice of bytes.